# « Pis demain je m'en vas su' madame lon la ! / Pis lundi je reviens ! » : madame qui ?

Tags: québec, paroles-de-chanson, musique, accents-régionaux, onomatopées

> Pis demain je m'en vas su' madame **lon, là** [lon, la/lon-la/lon la] !
>  Pis lundi je
>   reviens !
>
> [*Un dimanche au matin*](https://youtu.be/S9WyzmYPygk), Tout comme au jour de l'An (1987), [La Bottine souriante](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Bottine_souriante).

Dans cette *chanson à répondre* folklorique [du Québec](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musique_traditionnelle#Au_Qu.C3.A9bec) (voir aussi la pratique du [*chant à répondre*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chant_%C3%A0_r%C3%A9pondre), *inscrite à l'Inventaire du patrimoine culturel immatériel en France*) j'ai toujours cru qu'il s'agissait de « madame Lola », mais pas d'après les transcriptions des paroles qu'on trouve sur internet même si elles sont généralement peu fiables (je n'ai pas le livret de l'album). *Lon la* apparaît au corpus de livres de *Google* (mais il faut retirer tous les résultats équivalents à « on l'a » d'un français plus ancien, faut-il croire). Et on trouve entre autres une [chanson bretonne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musique_traditionnelle#En_France) comme « [Lon lon la](http://imslp.org/wiki/Lon_lon_la!_(Caplet,_Andr%C3%A9)) » (1903) avec musique d'[André Caplet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Caplet) (*Lon lon la. Les jours se passent, Vides, misérablement* [...]), considérablement moins festive ; ou une chanson de [Charles Marchand](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Marchand), [*Gai lon la vive la roulette*](https://youtu.be/BKN2yFHITvU) (1927)...

Je ne sais pas comment on appelle exactement le fait d'utiliser une syllabe, ou une forme d'onomatopée, pour fredonner un air (*la-la-la*, *ta-da* etc.), mais l'idée d'utiliser *lon* me surprend (quelque chose dans mon manque total d'érudition en musique/art ?) et je suis davantage habitué d'entendre un refrain entièrement composé de sons (par opposition à un tel élément qui, le cas échéant, apparaîtrait dans l'extrait sans crier gare en fin de phrase avec le complément, d'où ma confusion avec *Lola*, c'est-à-dire le nom que je pensais qu'avait la madame).

---

- Qu'est-ce que c'est que ce « *lon la* »-là : que représente-t-il pour
  qu'on l'utilise ainsi, comment l'épelle-t-on et avec quelle ponctuation le marque-t-on, qu'ajoute-t-il au sens (on s'en va où ?) ou à quoi que ce soit d'autre dans l'extrait, et quelle serait sa fonction généralement ?
- Est-ce le même *lon la* que le *lon lon la* de la chanson bretonne ; *lon la* forme-t-il un tout ou est-ce simplement deux « sons trouvés au hasard dans trois chansons » ?
- À quand remonte cet emploi de *lon la* dans la tradition orale chantée en français et comment nomme-t-on déjà l'emploi de telles syllabes/onomatopées dans une chanson ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Ce sont des syllabes qui n'ont pas de signification, et elle sont très communes dans les chansons traditionnelles québécoises (mais pas uniques à cette dernière: on les retrouve aussi dans le folklore irlandais, par exemple).

2) Certaines (comme *maluron*, qu'on entend [ici](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-M7HBsV1RA) ainsi que dans la chanson québécoise "L'arbre est dans ses feuilles" ou encore [ici](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IMtkxOthKoE&t=1h9m)) se retrouvent aussi en France, mais c'est peut-être "L'arbre est dans ses feuilles" elle-même qui vient de France. *Bargenton* ne sonne d'ailleurs pas québécois du tout.

3) Cette pratique dans la chanson québécoise est généralement appelée "turlutte".

*Lon la* n'est pas une formule de turlutte habituelle. "Le verre à la main rin tin tin" est plus proche d'une formule typique (qui emploie généralement au moins une consonne occlusive), mais je crois qu'elle sert ici uniquement à "compléter" la rythmique.

J'aurais tendance à croire que la phrase est en fait "su' madame Long, là". C'est à dire que "Long" (peu importe son orthographe exacte) représenterait ici un surnom ou nom de famille, et *là* n'est pas une syllabe de turlutte mais plutôt un marqueur d'emphase très commun en français québécois. [Jean Tremblay](https://fr.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jean_Tremblay), l'actuel maire de Saguenay, est reconnu pour en abuser au point d'être surnommé "Jean Là-là Tremblay".

Comment: Merci, bien intéressant ! Pour la [turlute](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17021015), ça semble être avec un seul t pour l'acception dont vous parlez. Et donc vous aussi vous pensez à un patronyme pour ce _lon la_-là. Ce serait un nom inusité pour moi, et le voyant je le prononcerais en anglais (_long island, long beach_), mais ça se peut ('un moment donné quelqu'un avec le livret va sûrement étayer ça), et dans ce cas, avec la grave, on aurait le marqueur en effet. Vous mentionnez Bargenton dans 2) : manque-t-il une phrase pour introd. cette idée/où se trouve ce mot ?

Comment: Pensez-vous que ce pourrait être une métathèse ou du verlan ? Merci encore !

Comment: Ce n'est absolument pas du verlan. Le concept est complètement inconnu inconnu de ce côté de l'atlantique, et d'autant plus que les chanson traditionnelles qui présentent de la turlutte prédatent le verlan de pas mal de temps. Si je Mentionne Bargenton, c'est que la chanson dans mon second lien est intitulée "Vive L'amourette en Bargenton"

Comment: Bonne Année ! D'accord, mais le verlan est vieux en Europe, et ça aurait pu être déjà verlanisé avant de débarquer ici, par exemple. Mais il y a une partie du sujet qui touche l'histoire de musique traditionnelle et les (inter-)influences et je n'ai pas du tout l'expertise. Mais vous laissez de côté complètement la chanson bretonne ici, et pourquoi elle qui n'a aucun lien avec le Québec ni Saguenay contiendrait lon-lon-la ?? Dois-je comprendre que vous pensez que c'est une coïncidence, ou que c'est distinct mais découle du fait français aussi pour d'autres raisons ? Merci !

Comment: Tout d'abord, à ma connaissance, le français hexagonal a eu très peu d'influence sur le français Canadien après la conquête (1759-1760), et que déjà avant on peut présupposer un minimum d'influence étant donné le faibles nombre de voyageurs. Secundo, il faudrait présumer qu'une large proportions des colons, dont les origines incluait quasiment l'ensemble du nord-est de la France, soient familier avec ce verlan. Tertio, les Bretons ne représentaient pas plus de 3% des colons. Finalement, on trace généralement plutôt le lien avec le style similaire des chansons folkloriques irlandaises.

Comment: Concernant ce dernier point, par exemple, les passage en "turlutte" de la chanson [Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRFHXMQP-QU) (*Mary Poppins*) seraient parfaitement à leur place dans une soirée traditionnelle québécoise, ce qui n'est absolument pas le cas de "lon lon la".

Comment: Merci pour les précisions ! Pour le [verlan](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlan), j'ai été surpris d'apprendre que même si son développement est surtout post-WWII, on avait des exemples bien plus anciens, par exemple _verjus_ pour _jus vert_ dans Furetière (1690). Parfois j'ai beaucoup de doutes car je vois qu'on a de nouvelles études, par ex. qui lient la _chasse-galerie_ à la _grand' chasse_ d'Europe; en d'autres mots le canot et la lévitation ne sont pas particuliers au Québec, on a la lévitation en version d'Acadie etc. (voir ce [pdf](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chasse-galerie))...

Comment: Je me souviens de la chanson dans Mary Poppins, intéressant. Je n'ai pas analysé la piste irlandaise dans ma recherche, mais c'est assurément productif. La musique bretonne est la plus connue du grand public français dit Wikipédia. Je ne sais pas si on aura d'autres perspectives sur le sujet mais je trouve ça bien intéressant. Merci !